# Unshuffle JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a huge array of data that I got from PDF files. The pdfs had 10 data items per page but because it was presented in two columns the data is shuffled. The first and last item of each group of ten items are in the correct position but the rest are not.

The order is now 0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9,10,12,14,16,18,11...
and i need it to be 0,1,2,3...

I've tried looping through the array and pushing items to a new array using different if statements but just cant get it right.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code with your attempt, otherwise we cannot help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that takes the data as you get it, and two more arguments to indicate the number of columns and number of rows on a page:

```js
function uncolumnize(data, numColumns, numRows) {
    let perPage = numColumns * numRows;
    return data.map((_, i) =>
        data[Math.floor(i / perPage) * perPage 
           + Math.floor((i % perPage) / numColumns) 
           + (i % numColumns) * numRows]
    );
}

let res = uncolumnize([0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9,10,12,14,16,18,11,13,15,17,19], 2, 5);
console.log(res);
```

It uses the `map` Array method, since the result (obviously) has just as many elements as the original data. The callback given to `map` does not use the value, but only the index. That index is used to determine the page, the row and the column. The latter two are reversed to rebuild a new index, and the data at that new index is returned.

Answer (score 0):

2 columns of 10 elements per page will have groups of 10 as `10n,10n+2,10n+4,10n+6,10n+8,10n+1,10n+3,10n+5,10n+7,10n+9`

There will be groups of 10 elements and one group (the last one) which will have 0-9 elements.

```
N = 5 //numbers of rows
len = numbers.length //numbers is the array
groups_of_2n_len = len/(2*N)
last_group_len = len%(2*N)


//For each group complete group
for(group_i = 0; group_i<groups_of_2n_len ; group_i=group_i +1)
{
    //Store those 2N elements in an array
    temp_array = numbers.slice(group_i*2*N,group_i*2*N + 2*N)
    element = group_i*2*N
    //Iterate row wise and fix the numbers
    for(temp_i = 0; temp_i< N; temp_i = temp_i+1)
    {
        numbers[element]=temp_array[temp_i]
        numbers[element+1] = temp_array[temp_i + N]
        element = element+2
    }

}

//For last group
if(last_group_len ==0) return

temp_array = numbers.slice(groups_of_2n_len*2*N,/*Till Last element*/)
element = groups_of_2n_len*2*N
for(temp_i = 0; temp_i< floor(last_group_len/2); temp_i = temp_i+1)
{
    numbers[element]=temp_array[temp_i]
    numbers[element+1] = temp_array[temp_i + floor(last_group_len/2)+last_group_len%2]
    element = element+2
}
//In case of odd number of elements, no need to handle 
//last element since it is already in correct place
```

Answer (score -3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Example highlighted:

```
var numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
console.log(numbers);

// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If numbers are in two separate arrays you can do something like this...

```
const array1 = [0, 4, 6, 5, 7];
const array2 = [1, 3, 2, 8, 9];
const combined = [...array1, ...array2];
console.log(combined);
```

Comment: I believe OP is showing the numbers purely for reference of  indexing not as actual data and you read the values too literally